# I have a 45% chance of losing money on my stock market trade and a 55% chance of winning.

Tags: probability, finance

I have an average $55\%$ chance of losing money on a given stock market trade and thus $45\%$ chance of winning. I want to know what my chances are of having $1$ through $12$ consecutive losing trades?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: not homework, just a 60 year old who cant work out the maths im trying 1.1/2   1.1/4  1.1/8 etc. I gather that'll get me there at 1.1/4112 for 12 consecutive losses?

Comment: Why don't you do the reverse trade:  then you will have a 55% chance of winning, and a 45% chance of losing.

Comment: good question, the 55% losers are trades, in this case options, that can only go to zero - the stock itself can only fall the zero $. On the upside, the price a stock can rise to is (theroretically)  unlimited. In my strategy, the option price rises at best  500%- 600%, the average win of the 45% winning trades is 102% profit and the average loss is -32% on the 55% losing trades - due to risk adjustment.  If i know the probabilities of a string of losses, i can set position size limits that would enable my portfolio to best handle a worst case scenario of consecutive losses. Looks like 4% size

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic binomial probability.

Just take the very first formular on this wikipediaarticle: [click me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution%22click%20me%22)
Where p would be your 55% and k the 1,2...,11,12 and n=12

Answer (score 0):

$0.55^n$ Where n is the number of consecutive trades.